# Xcode Version 6.2 no iOS 8.3 build target

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm pretty new to developing with Xcode and i can't build my application for iOS version 8.3 the build target for the OS is not listed in there . i checked the appstore to see if there are any updates available but there are no updates for Xcode . Anybody here that can send me on the right path for getting 8.3 as an option in the build target ?

Comment: The current version is Xcode 6.3 and that supports iOS 8.3. Xcode 6.3 runs only on OS X 10.10.

Comment: Well, the last version of Xcode is 6.3.1 and includes iOS 8.3 SDK. You can't have 8.3 in Xcode 6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need Xcode 6.3 and for that you will need osX Yosemite.

Comment: i'm running Yosemite , but there are no updates availeble for my xCode .
The last one i installed is version 6.3.1 on april 24th but my Xcode still remains version 6.2 . is there anywhere i should update or something ?

Comment: That's strange, maybe you somehow have 2 Xcode versions installed on your computer..try too look for another installed version and run it. Then make sure that on the menu Xcode-About Xcode it says 6.3.x

Comment: i have no clue on what went wrong with the updating but i just removed xCode and installed it again from the appstore and now i'm on 6.3.1 and i can build for 8.3 thank you for the help